# Can Pandas DataFrame to_dict and from_dict lose column order?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I call `to_dict` it returns a normal dictionary. However normal dictionaries do not preserve order.  The key for the dictionary is the column. Therefore, if had called `to_dict` on a dataframe and later call `from_dict` to reconstruct the dataframe, would that not suggest that I could potentially lose column order?

Comment: Depends on your python version. For a more specific answer please provide what version you are using. What you have tried and what the outcomes where. The answer to this question is something you could easily test right?

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, dictionaries preserve the order in which keys are inserted, so your assertion isn't true:

```py
In [7]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.DataFrame({'c': [5], 'a': [2], 'b': [1]}).to_dict())
Out[7]:
   c  a  b
0  5  2  1
```

Additionally, the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) provide a number of additional options for data structures such as OrderedDict:

```py
>>> from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
>>> df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict)
OrderedDict([('col1', OrderedDict([('row1', 1), ('row2', 2)])),
             ('col2', OrderedDict([('row1', 0.5), ('row2', 0.75)]))])
```